# Reactive consume MongoDB collection in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, reactive-programming

I'm trying to consume a MongoDB collection but i'm guess is there a better way to do this, better than my implementation.

These is my currently approach:

```
IMongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase("example");

        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);

            var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("SyncQueue");

            var documents = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();

            foreach (var doc in documents)
            {
                ProcessDocAndRemoveFromCollection(doc);
            }

        }
```

Would it be possible to do something like this below?

PSEUDOCODE:

```
IMongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase("example");

    var subject = new Subject<BsonDocument>();
    subject.Subscribe(doc => ProcessDocAndRemoveFromCollection(doc));


    >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

    when new doc in MongoDB Collection ----> subject.OnNext(doc);            

    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

The key point is, I want to avoid create an infinite loop to consume the collection

Comment: Unfortunately MongoDB has no kind of triggers. If your concern is to be able to stop the loop cleanly then use a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: @Gusman You can [watch a collection](https://devesh4blog.wordpress.com/2018/11/01/real-time-notification-with-mongodb-change-stream-in-c/) though.

Comment: @John Nice, didn't knew about it, it has been a while since I used MongoDB. That seems what the OP wants.